# android.defaultConfig.versionCode is set to 0, but it should be a positive integer. when running ionic cordova run android -l

Tags: ionic-framework

I had the following error when running `ionic cordova run android -l` for the [live reload debugging](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/livereload)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> android.defaultConfig.versionCode is set to 0, but it should be a positive integer.
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning for more information
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix it was to change in the `config.xml` and to add a number to `android-versionCode` and `version` in the `<widget>` tag.

Like this

```xml
<widget 
android-versionCode="1" // <-- Here
version="0.0.1"  // <-- And there
id="yourId" 
ios-CFBundleVersion="0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```